# How to have custom "pixel"/Object using Mat_ in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been working on integrating self organizing map functionality into/with OpenCV.

I wish to have the Mat file/object structure but instead of each "pixel" or element being an rgb value I want it to be a Node Object. I have the following toy/test code:

main.cpp

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    Mat myMat;
    myMat = Mat_<Node*>(5, 5);
    myMat.at<Node>(0,0) = new Node(); //<----- THIS IS WRONG WAY TO DO IT

    return 0;
}
```

Node.hpp

```
#ifndef SRC_NODE_H_
#define SRC_NODE_H_
#include <string>

class Node {
public:
    static int counter;
    std::string nodeString;
    int nodeInt;

    Node();
    virtual ~Node();
};
#endif /* SRC_NODE_H_ */
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

int Node::counter = 0;

Node::Node() {
    nodeString = "myNodeString";
    nodeInt = counter;
    counter++;

    std::cout << "Node Constructor Count: " << nodeInt << std::endl;
}

Node::~Node() {
}
```

I am trying now to get the correct instantiation of each node object. Am I correct in believing that I can use Mat_ to make a Mat with Node objects for the "pixel" values? If I am wrong is there another way I can approach this. I have previously used Node*** to make a 2d array where each element is a pointer to a node. Oh, also, I will not know the size of the SOM until runtime.

Edit:

If I use the following it compiles and runs but only the `Node myNode` actually calls the constructor for node. The other two seem to maybe only allocate space but not instantiate the objects.

```
Mat_<Node> myMat;
myMat.create(2, 2);

Node myNode;

Mat M = Mat_<Node>(3,3);
```

Comment: you probably cannot have a `Mat_<Node*>`. and even if, you would have to use `myMat.at<Node*>(j,i)` . imho, your 'design' is broken.

Comment: Still an interesting problem. I never thought of using my data structure inside opencv's Mat (probably because it is not intended to do so, better use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)